# Does vectorization change the complexity?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, complexity-theory

I wrote a code in MATLAB with the complexity  O(n^3). I removed one of the loop and used the vectorized form instead. As a result the run time decreased. I understand in general the vectorization enhances the performance. What I am not sure is that I assumed the vectorization does not change the complexity.

I did some experiments as follows:

When I increased the input size by factor of 2 the run time increased by about a factor of 2.5(I expected by about factor of 8).

Now I am not sure if my initial assumption(which is the vectorization does not change the complexity.) is valid. Does any one have an insight?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the function you use. For instance using a function such as `bsxfun` increases the speed while it is just a `for-loop` written as `c++`/`mex` file. In such cases, I do not think vectorizing the code changes the complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Do you know why the run time is not increased proportionate (when increases in input size)? When I used for loop it was close to expected increase but when I vectorized it was not close. I used MATLAB. I just gave a range to index(rather than on column) and remove the for loop.https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: @Crimson Well with vectorized approaches, you are processing more data per period of time, so there's lot more data transfers, which might be affected by the memory bandwidth, etc. So, I don't think it would be a linear scale. Vectorization vs Performance vs Memory is an unique game. I am not too conversant with the complexity definitions though.

Comment: Thanks  for the comment . So it seems it related to enhancing the load and store operations and data transfer rather than a change in complexity.

Comment: I'm mostly guessing, so only comment, but here goes. I don't think that vectorization should change complexity. I.e. I'd think that the vectorized version of `O(n^3)` code should also be `O(n^3)`, but with a much smaller prefactor. But here's the catch: this is only asymptotic behaviour (so you need very large `n` to clearly see this), and there's usually a lot of fluff in your code (overhead from the point of view of your vectorization) that scales differently. So you really need huge `n` and scaling across multiple orders of magnitude to say anything empirical about complexity.

Comment: @Andras Deak I agree. Since the ratio for  the first version was higher, I was not sure.

Comment: @Crimson since the original is much slower, there most of the speed difference comes from the "signal". In a vectorized scenario the overhead takes up a larger chunk of overall time, so the scaling of the "signal" doesn't reflect that much in the total time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very general way I think the difference is actually throughput (latency) vs number of operations (complexity). If you would build a very dedicated ASIC for you algorithm you would have to n^3 operations. By vectorizing you are saying that some of these operations can be performed independently from each other in parallel. Matlab and current processors are more clever and can do certain operations in 'parallel' e.g. a 64bit processor could do 2-32bit summations 4-16bit etc.

Think of two algorithms both in O(n^3), **a** where each operation must be done complete independent (you can vectorize this algorithm) and **b** the other where they must be series (you can not vectorize it). Special hardware for each of those would both require n^3 operations. However, by using more hardware/gates for **a** you can finish the task in as quick as 1 clock cycle, while for **b** more hardware/gates does not help you and the task will take n^3 clock cycle.

---

**EDIT:**

Some code to illustrate the vectorization speed, although complexity (#operation) would not increase

```
clear variable;

Iterations = 100;
n = 2^20;
a = randi(100,[1,n]);
b = randi(100,[1,n]);

profile on;
for loop=1:Iterations
    % Full vector approach
    vector = a*b.';

    % Partial vector approach
    vector2 = sum(a.*b);

    % Direct mathematical approach
    serial = 0;
    for id=1:n
        serial = serial + a(id)*b(id);
    end
end
profile viewer;
```

*now technically matlab has some extra overhead per operation like checking if the operation makes sense etc, thus slowing for loop significantly. But in general this is just an example to illustrate a trend.*

Comment: with this explanation if I am not misunderstood the complexity will decrease since most of parallel  version of an algorithm has less complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your explanation if I am not misunderstood the complexity will decrease(since the parallel version of an algorithm normally has less complexity). In the manual for vectorization I did not see an explanation about making it parallel.

Comment: Complexity will mostly stay the same, still in O(n^3) but maybe some different prefactors as @Andras suggested. What will change is that some operations will be run in parallel thus decreasing the time to get the answer. When it comes to complexity vectorization kind of implies parallel operations.

In general 'time' does not necessary indicate complexity, but rather thorughput. Particularly with MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I should read more about this. I am a bit confused, since I have studied parallel version for few sorting algorithms before. Mostly the purpose is enhancing the efficiency(rather than time)  , but the final complexity the (computation + communication ) will decrease at the end(from what i remembered).

Comment: I see, you might be thinking of [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Which naturally divide up the problem and can easily be vectorized/parallelized but they also divide up the problem into smaller problem and save complexity from that. This does not apply to vectorization/parallelization in general, I am adding some code to illustrate this in answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It seems it is different from the parallelization  that I had in mind . I need to learn more about vectorization.